# Is there how to get rows as it is being displayed on AG-GRID?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm having a really hard time to implement a MOVE-TO feature on ag-grid.

The objective is to jump to a visible cell after pressing enter on an external input text.

Currently I'm calling forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort for retrieve rows that are being displayed. But is not that simple when you start to deal with groups, orgHierachy, hidden columns, etc.

So, is there a way to get something like that on ag-grid api?

e.g.

```
  _________________
  |  A    |  B    |
  -----------------
0)| Loris | Ipsum |
1)|       | foo   |
2)|       | bar   |
  -----------------
```

GetRowsAsTheyREALLYAre:

```
[
   {index:0, A='Loris', B="Ipsum"},
   {index:1, B="foo"},
   {index:2, B="bar"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the Ag-Gird documentation use `getDisplayedRowCount();` for getting visiable rows.

ex

```
 getAllDisplayedRows() {
    var count = this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount();
       for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      var rowNode = this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(i);
      console.log("row " + i + " is " + rowNode.data);
    }
  }
```

Read [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-accessing-data/)

Comment: That is not exactly the point. forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort does the same already with an iterator. The problem is that depending on who you columndefs is defined, some items on DATA may not be necessarily visible, for example